# Accelerometer's G Value, for detecting a car crash, an experimental Android application

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing an android app which can detect crash of vehicle, by measuring its changing acceleration nd G value,
How to calculate G value?
Nd
How much G value is needed to detect crash?
Nd
How to detect very big shake event using accelerometer?.

My app is my BSCS final project, please help.

Note: i actually measured G value, nd set 12 G as trigger, but 12 G is variates on different mobiles, on some mobile it takes more svere crash nd on some mobiles it reaches to 12 instantly,
Does different accelemeters behave differently?

Comment: Dear i calculated G value by Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)/9.8, nd then set 12 G as my trigger,

Comment: @Bujutsu But it acts differently in different mobiles, sometimes it triggered on slight crash nd sometime on svere crashes

Comment: Hardware requirements for sensors on Android are described in the Compatibility Definition Document: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf. Not sure if the sensor specifications are appropriate to your use case.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks dear, but this not resolved my issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution:?